# NumPy/Python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created a NumPy array,

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2,3][4,5,6]])
```

I want to make the array look like this `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]` and also after I make change I want to return to the original structure.

Is there a NumPy command to run a function on all values, like `a[0] * 2`?

The result should be

```
[[2,8][2,5][3,6]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to *transpose* the array (think matrices). Numpy arrays have a method for that:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = a.T  # or a.transpose()
```

But note that b is now a *view* of a; if you change b, a changes as well (this saves memory and time otherwise spent copying).

You can change the first column of b with

```
b[0] *= 2
```

Which gives you the result you want, but a has also changed! If you don't want that, use

```
b = a.T.copy()
```

If you do want to change a, note that you can also immediately change the values you want in a itself:

```
a[:, 0] *= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` on the ndarray and pass it to `numpy.array`:

```
In [36]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

In [37]: b = np.array(zip(*a))

In [38]: b
Out[38]:
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

In [39]: b*2
Out[39]:
array([[ 2,  8],
       [ 4, 10],
       [ 6, 12]])
```

Use [`numpy.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) for a pure [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) solution:

```
In [44]: b = np.column_stack(a)

In [45]: b
Out[45]:
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

In [46]: b*2
Out[46]:
array([[ 2,  8],
       [ 4, 10],
       [ 6, 12]])
```